# rqt --list-plugins is empty even though I have some installed

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed `ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins`, but when I run `rqt --list-plugins`, it does not show anything. What is the problem?

Note:

I know the answer and am in the process of posting it. I didn't see a good place to add this to the ROS wiki, so I'm posting it here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192199/rqt---list-plugins-is-empty-even-though-i-have-some-installed/) by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My rqt configuration file in `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini` was out-dated, possibly because I upgraded my machine to trusty instead of doing a clean install. I deleted the old configuration file, and that fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) with karma: 111 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-08**:
+1. Btw did you try with the option like `$ rqt --force-discover` as suggested [in the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin#Install_.26_Run_your_plugin)?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.ros.org/users/6661/scpeters/) on 2014-09-08**:
That tutorial is titled "Create your new rqt plugin", so I didn't read it. I was just trying to use rqt_plot and none of the plugins were showing up.